# To poll or not to poll (in a web services context)

Tags: wcf, web-services, polling

We can use polling to find out about updates from some source, for example, clients connected to a webserver.  WCF provides a nifty feature in the way of Duplex contracts, in which, I can maintain a connection to a client, and make invocations on that connection at will.
Some peeps in the office were discussing the merits of both solutions, and I wanted to get feedback on when each strategy is best used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an event-based mechanism instead of polling.  In WCF, you can do this easily by following the Publish-Subscribe framework that Juval Lowy provides at his website, [IDesign.net](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#Operations).

Answer (score 2):

Depends partly on how many users you have.

Say you have 1,000,000 users you will have problems maintaining that many sessions.

But if your system can respond to 1000 poll requests a second then each client can poll every 1000 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think Shiraz nailed this one, but I wanted to say two more things.

1. I've had trouble with Duplex
   contracts.  You have to have all of
   your ducks in a row with regards to
   the callback channel... you have to
   check it to make sure it's open,
   etc.  The IDesign.net stuff would be
   a minimum amount of plumbing code
   you'll have to include.
2. If it makes sense for your solution
   (this is only appropriate in certain
   situations), the MSMQ binding allows
   a client to send data to a service
   in an async manner (like Duplex),
   but the service isn't "polling" for
   messages... it gets notified when
   one enters the queue through some
   under-the-covers plumbing.

   This sort of forces you to turn the
   communication around (client becomes
   server, server becomes client), but
   if the majority of the communication
   is one-way, this would provide a lot
   of benefits.  The other advantage
   here is obviously the queued
   communication - the server can be
   down and not miss any messages...
   it'll pick 'em up when it comes back
   online.

Something to think about.

Comment: Also: If you need two-way communication with MSMQ, you have to implement both endpoints separately.  The service would have a client and a service and the client would have a service and a client (that way both can send and receive messages).